# Facebook login button error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the error i got when i click on connect button:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

and this is the link of the connect button:

https://socialsitedirectory.com/socialbridge/connect-facebook?scope=publish_actions&callbackUrl=https://socialsitedirectory.com/socialbridge&isFromSocialPublisher=1&pluginKey=blogs&entityType=blog-post&entityId=931

I tried to add Valid OAuth Redirect URIs but no luck.

Comment: What did you add in Valid OAuth Redirect URI?

Comment: Also publish_actions permission will soon be removed

Comment: I added https://socialsitedirectory.com/socialbridge/connect-facebook

Comment: I tried to add the full link and the error disappeared, but as u can see the link has dynamic data

Comment: Then you figured it out. It can't be dynamic.

Comment: Which part of this is dynamic, and _why_?

Comment: as you can see it has a callbackUrl with some data in order to reload the previews post that the used created before he clicked on facebook login button